# Passing username, password, and token to simple_salesforce from env variables

Tags: python, authentication, environment-variables, salesforce

I want to authenticate into salesforce using simple_salesforce library in Python.

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

load_dotenv(find_dotenv()) # load env variables

# establish connection to salesforce API
sf = Salesforce(
    username=str(os.getenv('SF_USERNAME')), 
    password=str(os.getenv('SF_PASSWORD')), 
    security_token=str(os.getenv('SF_TOKEN'))
)
```

The code above results in:

> **SalesforceAuthenticationFailed at /admin/
> INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.**

If I hard-code this credential just like below it works.

```
sf = Salesforce(
    username='username', 
    password='password', 
    security_token='token'
)
```

I already confirmed that environmental variables are set in Linux (Centos) and was able to get those environmental variables (I printed username, password, and token right before establishing connection to test). Those credentials are correct and user is not locked. Can somebody help me figure out how to fix this?